# JUnit - Could not find class when trying to test

Tags: java, junit

I do NOT know much about Java. At this time, I'm trying to write a basic unit test using JUnit. My unit test runs fine from IntelliJ. However, I'm trying to run my test from the console window. In an attempt to do that, I'm executing the following:

```
java -cp /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13\ CE.app/lib/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.myCompany.core.app.MyIntegrationTests
```

When I execute this, I get an error that says:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: com.myCompany.core.app.MyIntegrationTests
```

I don't understand. I'm starting from the root directory of my app. My .class file is located at /root/target/classes/com/myCompany/core/app/MyIntegrationTests.class. So, from the root I tried running:

```
java -cp /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13\ CE.app/lib/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore target/classes/com/myCompany/core/app/MyIntegrationTests.class
```

I ended up getting a similar "Could not find class" error. What am I doing wrong? Why won't my unit tests run from the console, yet they run from within IntelliJ just fine?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not putting your classes on the classpath.

Comment: so, what should I be running exactly? I don't understand.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html